# Mobile device zoom in Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, mobile, web-applications

I've made a web app in GAS which is 400 pixels wide. I'd like this to zoom to fill the screen of a mobile device when loaded, rather than only filling half the screen (still using a fixed pixel width though).

I've tried using the viewport code below with no luck.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

Comment: Sorry, code didn't work with brackets...meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes"

Comment: GAS supports viewport now (as of December 2015). Example here: [link](https://plus.google.com/+MarcoColomboMow/posts/GXgRCh98HTu)

`var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('inputpage')
       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
       .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');`

Comment: @SujayPhadke you should post this as an answer.  I would up-vote it as it definitely works this way.

Comment: @Karl_S  thanks, done.

Answer (score 5):

This was address by Google in recent months and functionality was added, use the .addMetaTag() method.

Example:

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="..."/>
<meta name="viewport" content="..."/>

var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
output.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
```

Documentation on the method
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#addmetatagname-content

Related Forum
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4659

Answer (score 2):

GAS supports viewport now (as of December 2015).

Example (taken from this [link](https://plus.google.com/+MarcoColomboMow/posts/GXgRCh98HTu))

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('inputpage').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
```

Answer (score 1):

I’ve recently had the same problem and after some looking around stumbled on a logged issue on Google’s Caja project issue tracker http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1632.

The issue reported is exactly what you have described, where you are trying to zoom in on a webpage (generated by using Google apps scripts) when viewed via a mobile device. There is a work-around mentioned in a reply but finding it difficult in following the instructions and fixing the issue.

Comment: Interesting... it seems to suggest on there that the issue is with google apps script's "container" element ignoring the meta tag rather than the caja encription... I wonder if anyone is able to confirm that?

Comment: My understanding from the log report and Caja is that google apps scripts are specifically designed for embedding into host websites. The whole philosophy with Caja is to securely isolate the host website and third party code such as google apps scripts so that the host site can control how it interacts with it. I don’t understand how a standalone google apps script it generated and whether it does implement a host page but changing the host’s meta parameters and changing how the browser interprets it isn’t something you would allow third party software to do.

Comment: Is there really no way to create a standalone webpage that resizes for mobiles using google apps scripts? The only two methods i'm familiar with is either using viewport or doctype in directives for mobiles but in either case doesn't work .. Could someone please help

Answer (score -1):

Google doesn't seem to think this is an issue.  They consider access to meta-viewport an enhancement.  Only alternative I found was to write custom CSS for mobile and sniff it out using a media query.  See https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4659